# Hardwire dishwasher

Tags: electrical, gfci, dishwasher

Can you hardwire a dishwasher with the power coming from the load side of a nearby gfci?  The receptacle is on its own dedicated circuit with a 15 amp breaker.  Does code allow this type of connection?

Edit:
So the outlet is dedicated for the dishwasher since it was labeled dishwasher on the breaker. However the home had a cabinet there and the gfci outlet was right next to the cabinet. Now that the cabinet is gone, the dishwasher is wider and is in front of the outlet now. So I just wanted to load out of outlet and hardwire the dishwasher so I don’t have to relocate the outlet and still have ground fault protection.

Comment: Does the d/w currently have a plug, or is it currently hardwired?

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have said in a comment that the dishwasher will be in front of the GFCI outlet, I suggest you do not block that outlet with the dishwasher. If it pops it will be hard to reset, you won't even know.  And code does not allow *that*.

1. Install a GFCI breaker for this dedicated circuit.
2. If the junction box for the outlet is metal, remove the outlet from the box, and install a metal cover plate with a knockout hole so you can easily install the flexible metal connector to the dishwasher. Buy a connector with a 90° elbow at the wall end so the dishwasher can be close to the wall.
3. If the junction box is plastic I *think* you'll need to replace the box.  I'm not sure if there is a way to connect metal appliance tail to a plastic box.  You should ask a new question if you need to do that.

To answer the more obscure part of your question about whether a dishwasher can be hard-wired to a junction box that (still) contains a GFCI outlet that once was dedicated to the dishwasher: the answer is "no".  If the outlet is inaccessible, that's not to code.  If it *is* accessible, and *was* dedicated to the dishwasher, it now could be used by future occupants to plug in something that is very likely, this being a kitchen, to exceed 15A when combined with the dishwasher.

Answer (score 1):

Countertop outlets are required by code, usually 20 Amp circuits, and you could not use one of those for a dishwasher. Dishwashers need a dedicated circuit so feeding it from a GFCI outlet would not be allowed. Dishwashers can be fed from a 20 Amp garbage disposal circuit if total loading permits it. If the outlet isn't required by code, you could replace the GFCI outlet with a GFCI switch, no outlet or replace the breaker with a GFCI breaker. I doubt,though, that it's just an extra outlet laying around.

Comment: So the outlet is dedicated for the dishwasher since it was labeled dishwasher on the breaker.  However the home had a cabinet there and the gfci outlet was right next to the cabinet.  Now that the cabinet is gone, the dishwasher is wider and is in front of the outlet now. So I just wanted to load out of outlet and hardwire the dishwasher so I don’t have to relocate the outlet and still have ground fault protection.

Comment: The GFCI  must be accessible so if the washer will be permanently installed, you'll have to move the outlet.